# Memcached not listening

Tags: memcached

I installed [Membase's memcached distro](http://membase.com/products-and-services/memcached) on Windows 2003 R2 x64, but memcached.exe isn't opening any listening ports (I can see this through the TCP/IP tab in Process Explorer). However, if I copy the command line Membase uses to launch memcached:

```
"E:\Program Files\Membase\Server\bin\memcached\memcached.exe" -X ./bin/memcached/stdin_term_handler.so -p 11210 -E ./bin/bucket_engine/bucket_engine.so -B binary -r -c 10000 -e admin=_admin;default_bucket_name=default;auto_create=false
```

and launch this manually in a cmd, it opens the port 11210 correctly. However, it still doesn't work, and if I add a `-v` to the command line I get a lot of these errors:

```
2144: sasl result code:  -1
2144: Unknown sasl response:  -1
2160: sasl result code:  -1
2160: Unknown sasl response:  -1
...
```

Has anyone seen this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me as a permission problem. I don't remember the specific permissions but membase needs to have a permission to listen, start other apps and perform authentication/authorization.

Comment: +1 yes, I thought about it, but then I changed the service user to the same user I used to run it through command line, and the same thing happened